# URL-dependent PHP scripts in sequence

Tags: php

I'm attempting to display certain PHP scripts based on the URL used. I have it working without issue until I try to do it twice. What am I missing?

PHP:

```
<div id="firstbox">
        <span id='close' onclick="parentNode.remove()">CLOSE</span>
        <br>
        <b><a href="fulltext.php?page=burgundiofullh1">Burgundio</a></b>
        <?php       
        $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if($host == 'comparison.php?page=1.1.1') 
        {
            $url = 'homily1burgundio.txt';
            $homily = file($url);
            foreach ($homily as $line) {
                $result = array_filter(preg_split( '/\r\n|\r|\n/', $line ));
                if ( isset($result[0]) )
                    $line_array[] = $result[0];
                }
            echo "<p>" . $line_array[1] . "</p>";
        }
    ?>
    </div>
```

This works fine. However, when I try to display different text in a different box on the same page using the same URL, it just displays the same text as the first time.

Second box PHP:

```
<div id="secondbox">
        <span id='close' onclick="parentNode.remove()">CLOSE</span>
        <br>
        <b><a href="fulltext.php?page=griffolinifullh1">Griffolini</a></b>
        <?php   
        if($host == 'comparison.php?page=1.1.1') 
        {
            $url = 'homily1griffolini.txt';
            $homily = file($url);
            foreach ($homily as $line) {
                $result = array_filter(preg_split( '/\r\n|\r|\n/', $line ));
                if ( isset($result[0]) )
                    $line_array[] = $result[0];
                }
            echo "<p>" . $line_array[1] . "</p>";
        }
    ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: your if condition is the same. latest if override everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are over writing line_array. try this:

**Second box PHP:**

```
<div id="secondbox">
        <span id='close' onclick="parentNode.remove()">CLOSE</span>
        <br>
        <b><a href="fulltext.php?page=griffolinifullh1">Griffolini</a></b>
        <?php   

            $url = 'homily1griffolini.txt';
            $homily = file($url);
            foreach ($homily as $line) {
                $result = array_filter(preg_split( '/\r\n|\r|\n/', $line ));
                if ( isset($result[0]) )
                    $line_array1[] = $result[0];
                }
            echo "<p>" . $line_array1[1] . "</p>";

    ?>
        </div>
```